# AxWebBrowser full page Snapshot

Tags: vb.net, screenshot, axwebbrowser

Im currently enhancing an old software with an AxWebBrowser control. Let's say i navigated to www.yahoo.com and the page is too long, it's scrollable. I already done the part of screen capture but it's unable to capture the page in full page content. Now i want to have an option to let user choose whether full page capture or only capture the viewing part(scrollable). Is it possible?

Comment: Is it possible to capture the full page content? or is it possible to ask the user? you have not made your question clear.

Comment: Hi Zaf, i want to know whether is it possible to capture full page content...because i find a lot solution but they seems not really working. sorry for the confusing.

Comment: Hi Chrysler Pong Wei Loong, a simple search on google for full page screen grab gave several results, so without researching it too much, one would assume its possible, also you could check the following links
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5051/Various-methods-for-capturing-the-screen
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd183370(v=vs.85).aspx
I would assume the BitBlt method is not limited by the window size and scrollbars as it uses the HWND property to get the handle to the context, also dont forget

Comment: Sorry, I keep forgetting pressing enter submits the comment instead of adding a newline... so to continue...
Dont forget you may just find what you need with a simple search and finally this link too http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_7/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-complete-web-page/83766be5-30d3-4c79-b786-14bbff894419 - May possibly be your best shot

Comment: Hi Zaf, thanks for your replied. But i think your links are not the things i want. the thing i want is something like this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19881/Capture-Entire-Web-Page 
, but this solution only works for new WebBrowser control but not AXwebBrowser. and also this solution have some problem eg. capturing on yahoo.com or some site may output a blank result.

Comment: I have tried researching for whole month but still don't find any answer. appreciate if anyone could help :)